# Set Rows Attribute for Blazor (Server) InputTextArea

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am building a Blazor (Server) EditForm which contains an InputTextArea. By default, it looks like the InputTextArea creates a textArea with 2 rows, but I would prefer 4 rows for this specific application.

How do you set the number of rows for a Blazor InputTextArea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can simply add the `rows` attribute like below.

```
<InputTextArea @bind-Value="@prop" rows="4"></InputTextArea>
```

It does not require any C# as this is just html.

Comment: I thought I previously tried that, but clearly I didn't. I feel a bit silly now, but I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

I would love to know if there is another way, but after searching for a while, I was able to find this solutions.

1. In your C# code, create a property of type Dictionary<string, object>.

   ```
    Dictionary<string, object> inputTextAreaAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
   ```
2. Override OnInitializedAsync and add a new item to your dictionary.

   ```
    Dictionary<string, object> inputTextAreaAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        inputTextAreaAttributes.Add("rows", "4");
    }
   ```
3. Set the @Attribute property of the InputTextArea to your dictionary.

   ```
    <InputTextArea @bind-Value="@prop" @attributes="inputTextAreaAttributes"></InputTextArea>
   ```